# Python.Net: Load a second window in second appdomain using Python.Net

Tags: python, .net, wpf, multithreading, python.net

I am wondering how to start a new AppDomain and run a WPF window in that AppDomain?

My code is something like:

```
import clr 
clr.AddReference(r"wpf\PresentationFramework")
from System.Windows import Application, Window
from System.Threading import Thread, ThreadStart, ApartmentState
from System import AppDomain, AppDomainSetup, CrossAppDomainDelegate


class MyWindow(Window):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def start_thread():
        thread1 = Thread(ThreadStart(MyWindow))
        print ("Thread 1 domain:",thread1.GetDomain().FriendlyName)
        thread1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
        thread1.Start()
        thread1.Join()


    ads = AppDomainSetup()
    ads.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
    ads.ConfigurationFile = \
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile

    ad2 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ad2", None, ads)

    cadd = CrossAppDomainDelegate(start_thread)
    ad2.DoCallBack(cadd)
```

As a result, I got an error:

**System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type '__System_CrossAppDomainDelegateDispatcher' in assembly '__CodeGenerator_Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.**

I guess the challenge is to set the cadd object as serializable. But when I looked up for solutions, I did not find anything about how to do it in Python.

I am quite new to this field, probably I am wrong in the very beginning.

Thank you for your help in advance!